# shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not detecting Hash url change for inside view in html5

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am working on web + android project but thing is that i can not able to get url from shouldOverrideUrlLoading.
I think this is because there is nested html view and dynamic data assigning into html container.
There is sliding menu in html web view its same like facebook , gmail type sliding menu but its in html.
when you tap any item of that menu i cant get url ..( i want to just determine which button or menu item is tap by user).

if i try simple a href link than it works i get shouldOverrideUrlLoading url.

****I think my web developer loading one index page and into that he put one div tag and he just change the content of div tag when you move from one page to another and thats why i don't get url in shouldOverrideUrlLoading is there any other way to retrieve user click on button or item****

IS there any way to track loading of nested html pages.

Here is Index page of nested html , css , js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <title>Application</title>
        <!--
        <?php
            // Use that to serve the correct css file to the os using the app
            $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        ?>
        -->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/all.css">
        <script data-main="js/all" src="js/libs/require/require.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="page"></div>

    </body>

</html>
```

This is sliding menu

```
<ul class="left-navigation list">
    <li class="niv1"><h3><a href="">Accueil</a></h3></li>
    <li class="niv1"><h3>Votre compte</h3></li>
    <li class="niv1"><h3><a href="#add-video">Proposer une vid√©o</a></h3></li>
    <li class="niv1"><h3>Vid√©os</h3>
        <ul>
            <li class="niv2"><h4><a href="#video-list">Populaires</a></h4></li>
            <li class="niv2"><h4><a href="#video-list">+ comment√©es</a></h4></li>
            <li class="niv2"><h4><a href="#video-list">Derni√®res vid√©os</a></h4></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="niv1"> <h3>Concours</h3>
        <ul>
            <li class="niv2"><h4><a href="#contest-list">Tous</a></h4></li>
            <li class="niv2"><h4><a href="#contest-opened">En cours</a></h4></li>
            <li class="niv2"><h4><a href="#contest-closed">Termin√©</a></h4></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<ul class="right-navigation list">
    <li class="niv1 clearfix"><h3>Secteurs</h3>
        <ul>
            {{#secteurs}}
            <li class="niv2"><h4><a href="#sector{{secteur_id}}">{{nom_secteur}}</a></h4></li>
            {{/secteurs}}
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Android code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    HelloWebViewClient webViewClient = new HelloWebViewClient(); 
    myWebView.setWebViewClient( webViewClient);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

}    

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{ 
    @Override 
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
        Log.i("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i thing it's fine but yet if you can try below code hope it's working.

Answer (score -1):

Put this code before load url

```
    webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new webChromeClient());
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*16);
    String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(RenderPriority.HIGH);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    String databasePath = "/data/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/databases/";


    webView.getSettings().setDatabasePath(databasePath);
    //webView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    JavascriptInterface javasriptInterface = new JavascriptInterface(MainActivity.this);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(javasriptInterface, "Print");


private class Callback extends WebViewClient{  
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"shouldOverrideUrlLoading");
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"url: "+url);

        view.loadUrl(url);
        }
        return true;
        //return (false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"onPageStarted");
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"url: "+url);

        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }   

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"onPageFinished");
        AppLog.logString(TAG+"url: "+url);

        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    }   
 }
 private class webChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{
     @Override
        public void onExceededDatabaseQuota(String url, String databaseIdentifier, long currentQuota, long estimatedSize, long totalUsedQuota, WebStorage.QuotaUpdater quotaUpdater) { 
         AppLog.logString(TAG+"onExceededDatabaseQuota");
         quotaUpdater.updateQuota(5 * 1024 * 1024); 
     }      
     @Override
     public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
        MainActivity.this.setProgress(newProgress * 1000);
     }
 }

Applog.logString is nothing it's log.d so change it this is working for me very well
```

Comment: if i don't use normal html with href tag i got url into log..but in my case its different my web developer used div tag and according to that he change the contain of div tag not total page.. i am using one page index page but changing data of that index page..so thats why i dont get url..is there any other way to get user tap details

Comment: soryy can you explain you requriment what changing in you index page. are you move to another page or just refreshing index page?

Comment: its ome thing like one index page and that index page containt div tag and javascript is used to load other page into that div that...i mean div tag contain are gettig change when you tap menu item..but we are still on index page...just # hash url is get change..not main page

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3Wmt7wc9 see this is sample home page which get load into index div tag

Comment: @PankajAndroid which one of these lines is relevant to the issue at hand?