# Track url redirection android

Tags: android, url, redirect, webview

I am loading a Url into my `WebView`. It is a Url for a login page into a website . I want to track all the redirected urls especially the last one when the page loads after the user logs in.

Any idea how this can be done?

Comment: Implement `webviewclient` in `webview`

Comment: @SimplePlan I have done it.. But what methods do i override?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("url", url);
    startActivity(intent);
    return true;
  }
  }
```

Also see [here](http://www.catchingtales.com/android-webview-shouldoverrideurlloading-and-redirect/416/)

Answer (score 0):

check answer [shouldOverrideUrlLoading is not detecting Hash url change for inside view in html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19294329/shouldoverrideurlloading-is-not-detecting-hash-url-change-for-inside-view-in-htm/19295128#19295128) in that shouldOverrideUrlLoading method return loading url that you can store and check as per your requrement

Answer (score 0):

```
each and every url which is loading in webview can be tracked through 
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            //url parameter is the one which we needed
        }

this methods belongs to 
private WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    return true;
        }


        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        }

        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, android.graphics.Bitmap favicon) {

        };

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        }
    };
```